# Cannot SSH into AWS EC2 Instance, Blinking Cursor

Tags: ssh, connection, amazon-ec2

I cannot ssh into an EC2 instance I have created in AWS console.
I just get blinking cursor when I typed this command:

```
ssh -i "ansible.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This what I get in the terminal:

```
root@OMEN:/home/krillavilla/ansible# ssh -vv "ansible.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ansible.pem" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ansible.pem: Name or service not known
root@OMEN:/home/krillavilla/ansible# ssh -i "ansible.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I have tried restarting sshd services and uninstall sshd and reinstalled it. Nothing works.

***Update****

Correct command:

```
root@OMEN:/home/krillavilla/ansible# ssh -vv -i "ansible.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [52.34.81.7] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 52.34.81.7 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-34-81-7.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

**update**
[image]

Comment: @steeldriver I updated post with correct command

Comment: @steeldriver I verify ssh is there in my security group on aws console

Comment: Thanks for updating

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

It was the coffee shop wifi.
I changed my wifi and it connected successfully.